# How to store tags for images?

Tags: database, web

There are web-site where you can find and download beautiful wallpapers. They are divided into different groups, for example:

- mountains;
- forest;
- automobiles.

There are a lot of images and different tags. Amount of pictures and tags are rapidly increases from day to day.

A client wants to find a picture which presents both mountains and forest. So he chooses tags "mountains" and "forest". 
A web-developer has already put picture on a server and link it with the tags. But how? There might be four variants:

1. Tags are stored in one cell like that: "mountains|forest". In order
   to search for them it is necessary to split string value.
2. Tags are in array which was serialized and then saved in cell.
3. There are data base tables. One contains images ids and other
   properties. Other contains tags and it's ids. So tag and images are
   linked to each other by ids.
4. Completely different method: to use special source to store images
   and tags for them.

What way is the best? Are there any other ways to solve such task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a simple many to many relationship in the database.  Options 1 and 2 are bad options, and you shouldn't use them for a myriad of reasons.

We'll use a simple example for this.  First, you have a table with images in them.  It has three columns, `id`, `image_name`, `image_data`.  You also have a table with all your tags in them.  It has two columns, `id`, and `tag`.

Your many-to-many table will then have two columns named `image_id`, and `tag_id`.

So, lets say you have the following images:

```
1    'house_in_hills.png'    BLOB  
2    'mountains.png'         BLOB  
3    'old_shoes.png'         BLOB
```

And the following tags

```
1    'Mountains'
2    'House'
3    'Person'
```

Your many-to-many table would have entries that would look like:

```
1    1  # Image 'house_in_hills.png' has tag 'Mountains'
1    2  # Image 'house_in_hills.png' has tag 'House'
2    1  # Image 'mountains.png' has tag 'Mountains'
```

And so on.  I'd highly recommend reading up on Many-to-Many relationships.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between images and tags is called many-to-many. An image can have many tags, and a tag can be applied to many images. In a normalized database, you might represent this with the following tables:

```
image
======
id
file_path
...

tag
====
id
name
...

image_tag
=========
id
image_id
tag_id
```

Breaking out the relationship this way allows you to independently deal with each type of resource: images, tags, or a link between the two.